# adding new item to the nested data structure in reducer state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I have been trying to add a new item to my initial state with plain JS without using any utility library and it seems it's very complex.
Here the structure of my initial state:

```
  const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  events: [
    {
      year: 2021,
      place: [
          { id: 1, name: "BD" }, 
          { id: 1, name: "BD Test" }
       ]
    },
    { year: 2020, 
     place: [
         { id: 2, name: "AMS" },
        { id: 1, name: "AMS TEST" }
      ] 
    }
  ]
};
```

I want to add a new property to the matched item so that the state will modify like that:

```
    const initialState = {
     isLoading: false,
     events: [
    {
      year: 2021,
      place: [{ id: 1, name: "BD", newProp:"NewValue" }, 
             { id: 1, name: "BD Test" }
       ]
    },
    { year: 2020, 
     place: [
            { id: 2, name: "AMS" },
            { id: 1, name: "AMS TEST" }
   ] }
  ]
```

};
In my reducer,I have tried:

```
 case actionType.TOGGLE_INFO:
  return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.map((x) => x.place[0].id === action.id
      ? { ...x, place: [{ ...x.place[0], newProp: "new Value"}] }
      : x),
  };
```

That code updates the value in the state but then it only displays one item (place) from the events. Is there any way, I can still display all the events and update the selected place(by adding the new property) inside an event. I have been trying to fix it for a while now. so, any bits of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
My reducer so far:

```
   const initialState = {
     isLoading: false,
     events: [
        {
         year: 2021,
         place: [{ id: 1, name: "BD" }, { id: 1, name: "BD Test" }]
       },
       { year: 2020, 
         place: [{ id: 2, name: "AMS" }, { id: 1, name: "AMS TEST" }] }
  ]
};
const commonReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_EVENTS":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case "TOGGLE_INFO":
      console.log(state.events);
      return {
        ...state,
        events: state.events[0].map(event =>
          event.id === action.id
            ? { ...event, place: [{ ...event.place[0], isTouched: true }] }
            : event
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default commonReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to achieve but I'll try to help you anyway.

It'll be easier if you can pass the year also because of the way your data is structured but let's assume you can't:

```
    return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.map(event => {
        if(event.place.find(x => x.id === action.id)) {
            return {
                ...event,
                place: [...event.place, {newProp: "newValue"}]
            }
        } else {
            return event
        }
    })
}
```

I Hope that helps but if not I would like you to show me the before and after of what you are trying to achieve.

Update:

Initial State(you had duplicate keys so I changed it):

```
const initialState = {
isLoading: false,
events: [
    {
        year: 2021,
        place: [{ id: 1, name: "BD" }, { id: 2, name: "BD Test" }]
    },
    { year: 2020, place: [{ id: 3, name: "AMS" }, { id: 4, name: "AMS TEST" }] }
]
};
```

The Reducer:

```
const commonReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case "UpdateEvents":
        return {
            ...state
        };
    case "UpdatePlace":
        console.log(state.events);
        return {
            ...state,
            events: state.events.map(event => {
                const place = event.place.find(x => x.id === action.id);
                if (place) {
                    return {
                        ...event,
                        place: event.place.map(x => {
                            if (x.id === action.id) {
                                return { ...x, isTouched: true };
                            } else {
                                return x;
                            }
                        })
                    };
                } else {
                    return event;
                }
            })
        };
    default:
        return state;
}
};
  export default commonReducer;
```

`Place.js`:

```
return (
    <div>
    ID: { props.place.id }
    Name: { props.place.name }
    <div>{ props.place.isTouched ? "TOUCHED" : "" } < /div>
    < button onClick = { setTouched } > SetTouched < /button>
    < /div>
  );
 };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-black-m6il1

Comment: hey, thanks for replying. I am trying to add a new property to "place" when dispatching the "TOGGLE_INFO" action. So, in my components I have a parent component that displays the events first and then in the child component I am rendering the corresponding places from the events array. So, in my child component where I rendered the places,I want to fire up some click handlers that will add new items to the selected place. Hope that explanation helps you to understand. I am afraid that the code you have given, probably doesn't work

Comment: So from what I understand you are having trouble with updating your state? If so can you give me an example of the state before, an example of the action you are going to dispatch and the desired state afterwards? Just add it to your question

Comment: yes,I am having problems updating the state,I have added my reducer in the questions. It has the format of initialState(before updating the state)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-tdd-v3gbd?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js:0-746, also that sandbox might help you to understand,

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-black-m6il1 How about now?

Comment: man hats off, you just said my life,thanks a lot,I will still need to dig one level deeper,like:events:[place:[address:[id:1,text:"test"]]...so,I need to do one more map, I guess...

Comment: I find it hard to work with such deeply nested data so I would recommend trying to maybe normalizing your data(https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).

Comment: yes,I agree it's too complex that I should some how normalize that.

Comment: from your sandbox,I have tried to add one more deep items in the state address:[] and similarly tried to update state but seems I am still missing something. Any helps still with that..  https://codesandbox.io/s/small-brook-irc72?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js

Comment: The reducer seems fine but I can't find where you are dispatching an action with type "updateAddress" and where do you use the new "editing" prop...

Comment: yes, solved it as the reducer was fine,,,thanks again for checking though